# Is there a way to disable Auto Capitalisation on Xamarin Forms 'Entry' XAML

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have just started working in Xamarin and am writing an App targeting iOS and Android. I'm trying to keep pretty much all of my UI design in the common library between them and am starting to find the lines a bit blurred. My current requirement is to disable the auto-capitalisation on the 'Entry' tag object in XAML. Is this something that can be done by markup? I cannot find any property that would support this behaviour. If not, what should I do instead?

Comment: When I create a new `Entry` and type into it, the first letter is not capitalized. Do you perhaps specify a specific `Entry.Keyboard` or a `KeyboardFlag` on the `Entry`? Either directly or maybe through a style/base class? The following should force the entry to auto-capitalize, but I did not think it did it without that flag: `new Entry { Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.CapitalizeSentence) };` ([source](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/#Sentence_capitalization))

Comment: I'm using xaml to create my Entry instance, the markup is completely bare so only <Entry Text="{Binding MyText}"> is listed. I can access a property Entry.Keyboard but I can see no obvious content to put in there that would change this behaviour. I'm running this on an iOS simulator. Are you creating your Entry from XAML? What simulator are you using?

Comment: Ran it on an iOS simulator (iPhone 4s 8.4). You could still have a global `Entry` style defined in your `App.xaml` file or defined in your `ContentPage`?

Comment: @hvaughan3 I have no styles defined yet, this is literally a just out of the box XAML page, nothing defined anywhere either in the local file or in the app resources.

Answer (score 18):

If you plan to use this keyboard in a number of pages you will want to add the following code to your App.xaml's `ResourceDictionary`. If you want to use it in multiple places but only in a single `ContentPage` you will want to add it to the `ContentPage`'s `ResourceDictionary`. Otherwise you can add it directly to your `Entry`.

Also see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/#Specifying_additional_keyboard_options) for available `KeyboardFlag` values. I am just using `None` below.

If adding to a `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <Keyboard x:Key="NoCapitalizationKeyboard"
              x:FactoryMethod="Create">
      <x:Arguments>
        <KeyboardFlags>None</KeyboardFlags>
      </x:Arguments>
    </Keyboard>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Entry Keyboard="{StaticResource NoCapitalizationKeyboard}" />
```

Or directly to an `Entry`:

```
<Entry>
  <Entry.Keyboard>
    <Keyboard x:FactoryMethod="Create">
      <x:Arguments>
        <KeyboardFlags>None</KeyboardFlags>
      </x:Arguments>
    </Keyboard>
  </Entry.Keyboard>
</Entry>
```

Comment: To do this in the code behind...

Entry Input = new Entry
{
   Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.CapitalizeNone)
};

Answer (score 12):

A bit late but there is now a simple way to get a plain keyboard, with no flags:

```
<Entry
    FontSize="Small"
    Keyboard="Plain"
    Text="Text"/>
```

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.keyboard.plain?view=xamarin-forms).

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `Keyboard="Text"` - the `Default` keyboard performs the capitalisation.

Also check out the additional keyboard [settings](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/#Specifying_additional_keyboard_options) that can be applied. These allow you to toggle suggestions and other things.

Alternatively I recommend you create a simple [Effect](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/effects/introduction/) for `UITextField` and use the native iOS APIs to set the flags you need (`AutocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None;`).

We also have [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/ios/prevent-keyboard-suggestions/) on how to create a custom renderer to achieve the goal but since the introduction of effects, it seems to be a bit of an overkill.

Comment: I tried setting Keyboard to 'Text' but the result remained the same for me - I'm using the iOS simulator and it capitalises the first letter every time regardless. I'll have a read about Effects, but I suppose I'm just a little confused as to what my 'shared' view is doing for me if I have to do custom views or changes on a per operating system basis. I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental here, its early days for me in this world. Your effect part of the answer does seem to be suggesting a non XAML approach, is that me misreading it?

Comment: Same issue mentioned by The Senator, while using Android, whether on emulator or with a real Samsung, using "Text" still capitalize the first letter.

Answer (score 3):

There's a workaround to use entry without capitalization, such as a "username". For this you can simply use

```html
<Entry Keyboard="Email" Placeholder="Username"/>
```

Finally you'll get a non-autocapitalization entry and also you may use it as a email text if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Whether in the emulator or device in Android, you'll find this happens when xaml property in <Entry Keyboard="text" AND you are using a *physical keyboard*.

If you use the onscreen keyboard, even in the emulator (as you would normally using a phone or tablet in 99% of cases, this is not an issue). Setting Keyboard="Plain" as above in the <Entry tag solves the issue.

This also occurs in the  password entry dialog boxes. Annoying but doesn't look like anyone has marked it as a bug yet.