# Lowercase-only Input in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building a Xamarin.Forms app to be used with iOS and Android. The first `Page` of this app is a login form, with fields pictured below.

[image: App login form]

It's my intention to have the keyboard (when focused on the username field) expect all-lowercase characters.

I achieved this on a physical Android device by removing `Keyboard="Text"`. However, the iOS emulator seems adamant that uppercase is the way to go on that first letter, also showing this behaviour when I have the software keyboard up on the emulator.

I've really struggled to find more information for this when browsing Google. Is anyone aware of:

1. Expected behaviour of Xamarin.Forms here?
2. A way to work around this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Solution

In the end, programmatically setting the `Keyboard` property of the `Entry` as below worked a charm, without needing platform-specific code:

```
UsernameEntry.Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.None);
```

## Details

In [`Extensions.cs`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Extensions/Extensions.cs) within the source code of Xamarin.Forms, the Xamarin keyboard type is checked to determine the behaviour of the platform-specific keyboards. An example of this is below:

```
if (keyboard == Keyboard.Default)
{
    textInput.AutocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.Sentences;
```

Comment: Why is this suggestion downvoted? This is the most simple and straightforward way to achieve the functionality. Can someone shed some light on why this could be a bad thing?

Answer (score 5):

I found a simple xaml solution from alexgavru on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983468/is-there-a-way-to-disable-auto-capitalisation-on-xamarin-forms-entry-xaml). 
`<Entry Keyboard="Plain" />` worked for me.

Comment: Thank you this worked very good on Xamarin.Forms 4.6

Answer (score 4):

> Expected behaviour of Xamarin.Forms here?

The Forms' `Entry` on iOS is via the native `UITextField` and autocapitalization is handled via iOS's keyboard and that default behavior for the default iOS keyboard for an English locale is to capital words.

You can override the behavior via the `UITextField.AutocapitalizationType` property.

> The automatic capitalization style to apply to typed text. This attribute determines at what time the Shift key is automatically pressed. You can access the value of this attribute programmatically using the text field’s autocapitalizationType property.

#### Example:

```
someTextField.AutocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None;
```

> A way to work around this?

You can define a Forms' behavior to handle that change:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/creating

Or a custom `Entry` iOs renderer:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

#### UITextAutocapitalizationType:

```
public enum UITextAutocapitalizationType : long
{
    None,
    Words,
    Sentences,
    AllCharacters
}
```

Comment: Apologies for rushing to mark your answer as accepted - should have tried the code before doing so. Thanks for your quick suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use TextTransform="Lowercase".

Better late than never. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement except I wanted the keyboard to show all caps to enter a code value. So I used Effects provided by Xamarin to achieve this.
Here is the code for capitalizing it. But without any trouble you can change it to lower case.

Forms:

```
namespace VINEntryApp.CustomControls
{
    public class CapitalizeKeyboardEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public CapitalizeKeyboardEffect() : base("Company.CapitalizeKeyboardEffect")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Droid:

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("Company")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(CapitalizeKeyboardEffect), nameof(CapitalizeKeyboardEffect))]
namespace VINEntryApp.Droid.Custom
{
    [Preserve]
    public class CapitalizeKeyboardEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        private InputTypes _old;
        private IInputFilter[] _oldFilters;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            var editText = Control as EditText;
            if (editText != null)
            {
                _old = editText.InputType;
                _oldFilters = editText.GetFilters().ToArray();

                editText.SetRawInputType(InputTypes.ClassText | InputTypes.TextFlagCapCharacters);

                var newFilters = _oldFilters.ToList();
                newFilters.Add(new InputFilterAllCaps());
                editText.SetFilters(newFilters.ToArray());
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            var editText = Control as EditText;
            if (editText != null)
            {
                editText.SetRawInputType(_old);
                editText.SetFilters(_oldFilters);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

iOS:

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("Company")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(CapitalizeKeyboardEffect), nameof(CapitalizeKeyboardEffect))]
namespace VINEntryApp.iOS.Custom
{
    [Preserve]
    public class CapitalizeKeyboardEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        private UITextAutocapitalizationType _old;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            var editText = Control as UITextField;
            if (editText != null)
            {
                _old = editText.AutocapitalizationType;
                editText.AutocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.AllCharacters;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            var editText = Control as UITextField;
            if (editText != null)
                editText.AutocapitalizationType = _old;
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
<Entry>
     <Entry.Effects>
                    <custom:CapitalizeKeyboardEffect />
     </Entry.Effects>
<Entry>
```

Comment: Apologies for rushing to mark your answer as accepted - should have tried the code before doing so. Thanks for your quick suggestion.